# Can I use Sentry so i will trace TS source code, even though it has been compiled to Javascript?

Tags: typescript, sentry

I am using Sentry.io for tracing of thrown errors, however Sentry displays Js code (which is pretty logical because TS had been compiled to JS). Those traces are quite hard to read and maybe problematic for future me or anyone who will take care of the project. Is there anyway of handling this or can someone share example ?
Thanks community

Comment: I dont know nothing about Sentry.io but you can try https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig/#inlineSourceMap